# this regex is true but does not work in localhost

Tags: php, regex, localhost

i have a regex and I test it in [regepr](http://regexr.com/3dpas) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wG0eV1/2)

but it is not work in localhost!(my xampp version in 7.0.6)
my code is the following code

html.html

```
{block content
ddggggggggggggggg
/endcontent}
```

file.php

```
$pt="~\{\s*block\s*-?\s*(\w+)[\s+|\~](.*)\/end\1}~s";
#Blocks#
preg_match($pt, file_get_contents('html.html'),$match1);
print_r($match1);exit;
```

I am guessing the problem is \1 because the following code is work correctly

```
$pt="~\{\s*block\s*-?\s*(\w+)[\s+|\~](.*)\/endcontent}~s";
#Blocks#
preg_match($pt, self::$tmp,$match1);
print_r($match1);exit;
```

why first code is does not work in my localhost? 
do you know what is the problem?

html.html file is not static and maybe diffrent I need a dynamic regex such as first regex

Comment: Use single quotes around the regex. I also think you need a `()` around `\s+|\~` if you want to match *either* 1+ whitespaces *or* a `~`. Try `$pt='~\{\s*block\s*-?\s*(\w+)(\s+|\~)(.*)\/end\1}~s';`

Comment: vote ... PERFECT! please post your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a single quoted literal to make `\1` be treated as a backreference (otherwise, you need to double escape it).

Also, to match either 1+ whitespaces or a `~` you need to use *grouping* with parentheses, not a character class. Note that `[\s+|\~]` matches 1 character: a whitespace, a `+`, `|` or a `~`, and I doubt you actually want that behavior.

Use

```
$s = "{block content\nddggggggggggggggg\n/endcontent}";
$pt='~\{\s*block\s*-?\s*(\w+)(\s+|\~)(.*)\/end\1}~s';
preg_match($pt, $s, $match1);
print_r($match1);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/P9P2xg)